# Any way to reset volume level after unplugging headphones?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, audio, headphones

I have a MacBook Pro, running Mojave, that I take between work and home.

When at home, I plug a set of speakers into the headphone jack and play music through the speakers. In order to get a reasonable volume level on the speakers, I need to crank the volume on the Mac all the way to the top.

I forget about that volume setting when I take it to work and put on some actual headphones, and then blow my ears out with the full volume!

Is there a way to make the Mac reset to a default (reasonably low) volume for the headphones after I unplug?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a third-party app like [Keyboard Maestro](https://www.keyboardmaestro.com/main/) or [EventScripts](https://www.mousedown.net/software/EventScripts.html) to trigger a low volume setting script whenever you plug your headphone!

For exemple, with EventScript:

- Click on *Open Folder* from EventScripts menu in order to open the scripts folder.
- Add the script you want to be triggered, in your case something like `do shell script "osascript -e 'set volume 1'"` (note that set volume function works from 0 to 7, 0 being mute and 7 maximum volume).
- Click on *Choose Script* from EventScripts menu and select the script to be used.
- Add the event *Headphone connected*.

See my own setup as exemple to quit or launch *Boom* whenever headphone or Bluetooth device is found:

[image]